# What does "Idiomatic Access" mean?

Tags: terminology

What does "Idiomatic Access" mean? What's the big idea?

Here is the phrase in a sentence:

> Neo4j was originally conceived as an embedded Java library intended to
> provide idiomatic access to connected data through a graph API.

The phrase is, ironically, an idiom, i.e., "a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words."
Hence, I can't figure out what it means!

Comment: BTW, while I'm answering it here, questions about terminology (like questions about standard practices) are often more topical on [softwareengineering.se] StackExchange, whereas StackOverflow's focus is questions grounded in code. (The help center's on-topic page for each site is the canonical source for guidance in making that decision).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is that the API complies with local (Java) idioms: common practices; thus, that it will feel natural to folks familiar with other Java APIs.

This is an innately subjective claim to analyze (though for given languages/communities there may be objective practices which are common, standardized, and generally agreed upon as part of what constitutes an idiomatic library).

"Idiomatic" is thus the relevant term -- "access" is simply part of what Neo4j is doing (providing access to your data); the descriptor as "idiomatic access" is implying that this is access through an idiomatic API.